# Cartesian axis labels in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid.axislines import SubplotZero
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

if 1:
    fig = plt.figure(1)
    ax = SubplotZero(fig, 111)
    fig.add_subplot(ax)

    ax.axhline(linewidth=2.0, color="black")
    ax.axvline(linewidth=2.0, color="black")

    ax.set_xticks([1])
    ax.set_yticks([1])
    ax.set_xticklabels(['x'])
    ax.set_yticklabels(['y'])

    for direction in ["xzero", "yzero"]:
        ax.axis[direction].set_axisline_style("-|>")
        ax.axis[direction].set_visible(True)

    for direction in ["left", "right", "bottom", "top"]:
        ax.axis[direction].set_visible(False)

    x = numpy.linspace(-0.5, 1., 100)
    ax.plot(x, numpy.sin(x*numpy.pi), linewidth=2.0)

    plt.show()
```

which produces this graph:

[image: graph]

Two things:

1. The "y" label is on its side - how do I make it vertical?
2. Both "x" and "y" labels are not on the line of the axis - I want them to appear directly after the axis arrows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple way to achieve this is to use the [`text`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=annotate#matplotlib.axes.Axes.text) or [`annotate`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=annotate#matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate) methods of the `Axes`, with a kwarg `transform`.

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid.axislines import SubplotZero
from matplotlib.transforms import BlendedGenericTransform
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = SubplotZero(fig, 111)
fig.add_subplot(ax)

ax.axhline(linewidth=2.0, color="black")
ax.axvline(linewidth=2.0, color="black")

ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])

ax.text(0, 1.05, 'y', transform=BlendedGenericTransform(ax.transData, ax.transAxes), ha='center')
ax.text(1.05, 0, 'x', transform=BlendedGenericTransform(ax.transAxes, ax.transData), va='center')

for direction in ["xzero", "yzero"]:
    ax.axis[direction].set_axisline_style("-|>")
    ax.axis[direction].set_visible(True)

for direction in ["left", "right", "bottom", "top"]:
    ax.axis[direction].set_visible(False)

x = numpy.linspace(-0.5, 1., 100)
ax.plot(x, numpy.sin(x*numpy.pi), linewidth=2.0)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: A totally simple solution! You rock and I will now name my firstborn 'nordev'